# Deserialize date with PagedResources/embedded object. Jackson. Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, objectmapper

I defined `@Bean` `objectMapper` and set the date format like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

And it works when method return the normal `ResponseEntity<SomeDTO>`.
Sample JSON response:

```
{
    "id": 888,
    "createdDate": "2017-11-06 13:50",
}
```

But when my controller method returns: `ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SomeDTOResponse>>`, then `createdDate` isn't deserialized and I get:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "someEntityResponseList": [
            {
                "id": 877,
                "createdDate": 1509877100151
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        ...
    },
    "page": {
        ...
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<SomeDTOResponse>> getAllActiveAuctionsForLoggedUser(
        Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {
    Page<SomeEntity> someEntites = someEntityService.getAllSomeEntities(pageable);

Page<SomeDTOResponse> response = assembler.toResource(someEntites.map(entity -> mapToResponse(entity))
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When I put breakpoint in last line `return...`, the object `response` contains: `createdDate = {Timestamp@12184} "2017-11-05 10:54:14.345"`. `mapToResponse()` it's my custom method, but it's not the problem.
So how can I get the correct result, correct deserialization?

My other classes: `SomeDtoResponse` and `SomeEntity`.

```
@Data
public class SomeDtoResponse {

    private Long id;
    private Date createdDate;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_ENTITY")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "SOME_ENTITY_ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Date createdDate;
}
```

Comment: What is `ResponseEntity` and `PagedResources`?

Comment: @talex, `ResponseEntity`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html and `PagedResources`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/PagedResources.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Date class you are using should be of following type:

```
import java.util.Date;
```

If it's of Java.sql.Date, then it cause the problems like you are facing.
I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: That's not it, unfortunately. I checked it and I use everywhere `java.util.Date`